# Unable to unzip matlab2015a.iso.bz2 file in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-installation, iso, matlab

This is Prof. Kalyan Chatterjee.

I have recently purchased a new laptop which has Ubuntu 17.10 installed by default. I am new to Ubuntu. Now, I need to install Matlab in Ubuntu. I have downloaded the software and the file is Matlab2015a.iso.bz2

Now, I am unable to unzip the file and extract the iso file and install Matlab.

Will be highly obliged if anyone helps me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The extension suggests that the file was compressed with bzip2.

In order to unpack the it, please try `bzip2 -d Matlab2015a.iso.bz2` in a terminal.